# Loop through column B foreach value in column A to find duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble looping through data in an excel spreadsheet.

FOR EACH value in Column A search for the value in all of the Values in Column B. **IF True** insert "duplicate"

so far I've tried multiple variations of: `=IF(A2=$B$2:$B$14,"duplicate",)`

I've tried `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` and `INDEX` with `MATCH` but haven't to have been able to figure this out.

I believe a vba script would be considerably more efficient but can't seem to figure it out, can you help?

Comment: Did you try the simple `COUNTIF()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do it with a formula, as your post suggests you have tried use

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"","duplicate")
```

For a VBA solution try this

```
Sub CheckForDups()
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim rCompare As Range
    Dim rResult As Range
    Dim vSource As Variant
    Dim vComapre As Variant
    Dim vResult As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rSource = Application.Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Columns(1))
    Set rCompare = Application.Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Columns(2))
    Set rResult = Application.Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Columns(3))
    vSource = rSource
    vComapre = rCompare
    rResult.Clear
    vResult = rResult
    For i = 2 To UBound(vSource, 1)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(vSource(i, 1), rCompare, 0)) Then
            vResult(i, 1) = "duplicate"
        End If
    Next
    rResult = vResult
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 For suggesting both solutions :)

Comment: Thank you. The formula works as intended. However the VBA does not. For brevity I'll use the formula. Thank you again.

Comment: When I tested I got the same results with both. What does the VBa not do for you?